# What is this flicker I get while tracking a camera?

Tags: camera, tracking

After having my camera tracked, I decided to put in a cube for testing. But then I've noticed this strange artifact where every object kinda flickers and changes it's rotation.

[image]

Comment: note: some retracking and resolving seems to have fixed it, but i still wanna know what the problem was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clearly see the tracker shifting on the video posted on the question, and it happens at the moment where the reconstruction fails.

**Successful reconstruction can only be achieved with accurate tracking**

You should aim to have a solve error of less than 0.3 pixels.

There are plenty of tools to help you get more accurate tracking.

Read:

[Solve error high with good track?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53435/solve-error-high-with-good-track/53442#53442)

[Motion Tracking. What do the graphs represent and how are they useful?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/motion-tracking-what-do-the-graphs-represent-and-how-are-they-useful/14331#14331)

[Does the motion tracker follow a point if it changes colour throughout the video?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141042/does-the-motion-tracker-follow-a-point-if-it-changes-colour-throughout-the-video/141054#141054)

---

## For a comprehensive post on motion tracking tips read

## [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)

Comment: will a better solve also help me with my world alignment issues? i've been having this problem where the trackers and the camera are slightly tilted on Y and X axis and they're not on Z = 0, so I have to rotate my model for it to look good

Comment: different questions should be asked in a new post, not as comments... but before you post you can also use the big "search on blender" box at the top.